# VSTS field mapping

Tags: azure, tfs, project, ms-project

I am trying to modify the field mapping between VSTS and MS Project.  The issue is that the command exe does not work on TFS as SaaS, on Azure cloud specifically, which is what we are using.

What can I use to first download the mapping, I assume the same tool will do the uploading?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the field mapping between VSTS and MS Project is not supported.

Comment: Is this now out of date?